# unable to execute s2ui-override layout

Tags: grails, grails-spring-security

Using Grails 3.1.9, spring-security-core 3.1.1 and spring-security-ui3.0.M2 I get the following when executing
grails s2ui-override layout
Command [s2ui-override] error: class path resource [layouts/springSecurityUI.gsp] cannot be opened because it does not exist (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace) 
Any dieas on how to fix this or if spring-security-ui is even worth using? I noticed the only releases appear to have been milestone releases.

Answer (score 1):

Same error here... I think I simply used the template from source: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ui/blob/master/grails-app/views/layouts/springSecurityUI.gsp